# Why I cannot see the activities registered to a contact in her dashboard (frontend)?

Tags: activities, user-dashboard

Why I cannot see the activities registered in a contact profile, in his dashboard (frontend), when I can find it as a contact in the backend?.  I´m a very newbie with this amazing software. Thanks

When I see the contact dashboard from the front end, there says under the title: your Activities.... You are not registered on any activity, But when I go to that contact dashboard through the administration backend, the activities are there!!. So I don't understand, really... I need some experts to help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think by "registered" you mean "assigned". Check the "assigned to" field on those activities - in order for the activity to appear on the contact dashboard the person needs to be listed in the "assigned to" field.

As per comments below you're wanting the "with contact" to be the field that controls their activities. You can do this with search kit:

[image]

Note also I've added a "display" page you can see in the left sidebar. The link to that page is the link you would put in the menu for users to see their activities. This is on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and should be there for the next 15 hrs or so if you want to see it there.

Comment: Hi Demerit, thanks for your reply. In the activities form we have "created by" which is the person who creates that activity, "assigned to" the staff who will be in charge of developing that activity, and "with" which is the contact who is the object for that activity.

Comment: In this case, the activity is to fill a questionnaire (for the user) to be sent to the member of the staff to follow it up with the user. I create the activity to open up the questionnaire form, assigning the activity to a member of my staff and "with" where I place the name of the user (contact) . and then I save it. The idea is to drive the user to go to the website (frontend) and click on the right button to open up his CiviCRM "control panel" where he will find the activity I created for him.

Comment: Well If I do that from the user profile , I can see all his control panel, but nothing in "activities", the field shows that there's no activities registered witn that profile...If I go to search for activities...the activity is there, with the user's name ... So I don't understand what's happened... If I create a contribution, for instance, for that user, that appears immediately on his control panel, the same for creating a membership, or making a commitment, etc, but if I create an activity... it doesn't appear on the Control panel... ???. Really desperate with issue.. :-O

Comment: Ok I see. So the contact dashboard won't show activities where the person is the "with contact". There's maybe a couple options, but if you're using drupal I would suggest using drupal views to show this data on the front end for the user: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/. You could also do it with search kit, which you'll need to enable first under Administer - System Settings - Extensions.

Comment: Exactly!. You´ve got it. I´m using Joomla.

Comment: I´m exploring the search kit you mentioned, Thanks . :-)

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer above with a screenshot.